# Null value response on login

Tags: android, google-play-services, beta-testing

We have just uploaded the app for the Beta testing on Google play but while testing it's showing null value response on the login. Although the app is working fine if we are testing without the Google play. We have checked all the API's are working fine too.

Testing the app through the Google play beta testing.

Comment: This is a pretty general explantation. Please add some details about how & where you are logging in, maybe some code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.